# Chargaff Rules (confusion)

Tags: cell-biology

A professor of mine wrote that: $\frac{A+T}{G+C}$ is constant in double stranded DNA of different origin. However

The Chargaff rules state that due to base pairing in the DNA it holds that :

$A=T$ and $G=C$ and from that follows that $A+G=T+C$ in all DNA molecules

and thus: $\frac{A+G}{C+T}$ should be constant, no?

Who is in the wrong?

Comment: Was your professor talking about Chargaff rules or about GC content? Why didn't you ask the professor to clarify?

Comment: Constant in what sense? For all organisms? Please edit your question and make sure you recall correctly and completely what your professor said. And please, no ‘rules’ in any argument — just invoke what is known about the structure of DNA.

Comment: It states verbatim: for double stranded DNA of different origins it holds that : $\frac{A+T}{G+C}$ , the ratio is wrong, and the one I gave in my answer is correct, right?

Answer (score 4):

Context is important.

A/T ==  1 and G/C == 1 (approximately, to within a measurement error) are [Chargaff's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chargaff%27s_rules) for double-stranded DNA, occurring because A pairs with T and G pairs with C.

(A+T)/(G+C), or (G+C)/(A+T+G+C), are [completely different ratios unrelated to Chargaff's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GC-content). These are roughly constant across individuals *for a given species* and can be used to distinguish different species' genomes in an approximate manner.

I am not your professor, but it is possible in writing what they wrote, the professor was referring to whole-genome GC content within members of a species, in which case the professor is correct. If the professor was discussing Chargaff's rules, then the professor was wrong, but probably just made a mistake in writing: these things happen.

Comment: He states (verbatim): with double stranded DNA of different origin , the ratio $\frac{A+T}{G+C}$ is constant. Your answer doesn't really answer or help with anything , and just creates more confusion.

Comment: @schokakola I prefer to not just assume your professor is an idiot: in my experience, assuming people are idiots is counterproductive when other explanations exist. Thinking through multiple possible meanings is a good way to test your knowledge, so that was the intent of my answer. I've clarified my answer to make clear that if your professor wrote that ratio referring to Chargaff's rules, it is a mistake.

Comment: Read your "answer". It doesn't answer anything that I stated in my question. Do yourself and me a favour and stop replying to me please and let somebody who understands what I am asking answer instead!

Comment: @schokakola Can you clarify what exactly is still unclear to you compared to what you already know? "Your professor is right" or "your professor is wrong" is not an appropriate answer for Biology.SE, answers need to explain the concept and underlying biology.

Comment: I am asking whether the ratio I stated is correct or not. It's a very simple matter if you understand what I am asking. The answer is either yes or no. What you are doing is posting mindlessly anything that could peripherally have anything to do with the question in order to sound smart without answering the question itself. Stop.

Comment: Let me remind you of the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) - I am being very patient with you because you are addressing me, but if you were addressing anyone else I would not have such patience. See also https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3377/homework-questions

Comment: As I've said before. You not only didn't answer (or read and understand) my question, you intentionally added more confusion to make things MORE unclear just to sound smart. I don't want to have to deal with "you". I'm looking for somebody who is knowledgable in this area and can give a clear answer for which I'm very thankful.

Comment: @schokakola The answer to your question depends on the context. I don't want you to go to your professor and tell them they are wrong if they are actually correct but you misunderstood. Therefore, my answer gives two explanations: a case where they could be wrong (if they were in fact talking about Chargaff's rules), and a case where they could be right (if they were talking about something else). Now you'd have to go to your notes and find what the context was so that you know which one is the case. The only one here who is knowledgeable about what was said in your class is you.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, or it is unclear to you, then don't answer! Judging from your answers, you have no clue what I'm asking (you didn't even consider the ratio I gave because you are only interested in posting whatever you want to sound smart). After 100 comments, I still don't know whether the ratio I wrote is the correct one or not, instead you started a discussion about why I did or didn't ask the professor etc. etc. everything that has nothing to do with the question itself. Just save yourself the time and don't answer/reply if you don't understand the question.